# Force DialogFlow's Slack Integration to Reply in Thread

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, slack, slack-api

When I look through my StackDriver logs I don't see anything that gives me anything I recognize from Slack (other than the text itself).

I'm looking at having DialogFlow reply *in a thread* to specific messages but I haven't been able to get any "TS" values or even "Channel" values.

How can I reference this in a Custom Payload response so that DialogFlow replies in a thread?